# Centralise the title of UIButton as show in the Image Below Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, text-alignment

I want to show Button title like this

[image]

but my output is comming like this even after centralising the title

[image]
 frmbtn is the outlet of button And the Code I am Using for this is

```
 frmbtn.setTitle("From Station\nSTN\nSTATION NAME", forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    frmbtn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 3
    frmbtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center
```

And Can we put different text sizes in the button title ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is whole as you want.

[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var str : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "From station\nSTN\nStation Name")
        str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20), range: NSRange(location: 13,length: 3))
        button.setAttributedTitle(str, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
        button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing..! I thought it was impossible till now..!! Worked As Needed...!! Ek Dum Jhakas...!!

Answer (score 3):

in Easy way you can also give space like this:

```
 frmbtn.setTitle("From Station\n     STN\nSTATION NAME", forState: UIControlState.Normal) \\give here space after \n and see the result

    frmbtn.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 3
    frmbtn.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.Center
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the text alignment on the `titleLabel` itself. Also you can change the font size as part of the `font` property.

```
    scanButton.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 3
    scanButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    scanButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(40);
```

Answer (score 1):

To set a multiline title on a UIButton, [check this forum](http://unsolicitedfeedback.com/?p=59) post which describes changing the button label.

```
myButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
[myButton setTitle:@"From Station STN station name" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```