# Multiline text in UIButton in Swift iOS 8.0 doesnt work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

With code below

```
    self.answer4.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    self.answer4.setTitle(questions[3]["answer4"] as? String, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

a big line of text in `UIButton` don't transfers to the second line it just lies on single line and a big part of text is not visible

I tried

```
    self.answer4.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

but compiler complains about usage of unresolved identifier

also I tried setting word warp in attributes inspector - nothing happens

Comment: Check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543245/centralise-the-title-of-uibutton-as-show-in-the-image-below-swift

Comment: crashes with Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'NSMutableRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:: Out of bounds'

Comment: var str : NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: (questions[generatedQuestion]["answer4"] as? String)! )
        str.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20), range: NSRange(location: 13,length: 3))
        self.answer4.setAttributedTitle(str, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.answer4.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByWordWrapping
        self.answer4.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .Center
        self.answer4.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Comment: What you are doing? Just copy and paste. Please see that why the NSRange is used in that answer. It's not necessary in your question. I have just given the for reference.

Comment: so what are you referencing in particular ?